# binary search tree, insert method won't compile

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm attempting to write my own binary search tree in java.  I have written all my methods and I am now trying to write a program to test the methods.

However, when I try to implement my "insert" method, it will not compile and I have no idea why.

```
public class lab05driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BST q = new BST();

    int a = 5;
    String b = "jed";
    double c = 1.8;
    char d = 'r';
    boolean e = false;
    int f = 35;
    String g = "yay";
    double h = 2.1;
    char i = 'i';
    boolean j = true;

    Integer k = 5;
    q.insert(k);    
}}
```

and my BST class looks like this:

```
public class BST implements myBST {

    private myTreeNode root;


    public BST() {

    }


    public void insert(Comparable x) {
        if(root == null) {
            root = new myTreeNode();
            root.data = x;
        } else if ( !lookup(x) ) {
            root.insert(x);
        }

    }


    ...more code...

}
```

and, myBST looks like:

```
public interface myBST {
    public void insert(Comparable x);
    public void delete(Comparable x);
    public boolean lookup(Comparable x);
    public void printPreOrder();
    public void printInOrder();
    public void printPostOrder();
}
```

finally, myTreeNode looks like:

```
public class myTreeNode {

    public myTreeNode() {

    }

    public Comparable data ;

    public myTreeNode leftchild;

    public myTreeNode rightchild;

    public myTreeNode parent;

    public void insert(Comparable d) {
        //if less than
        //does left exist? if it doesnt, make it, give it d
        //if it exists call insertrecursive on rightchild
        if(d.compareTo(data) <= 0) {
            if(leftchild != null) {
                leftchild.insert(d);
            } else {
                leftchild = new myTreeNode();
                leftchild.data = d;
                leftchild.parent = this;
            }
        } else {
            if(rightchild != null) {
                rightchild.insert(d);
            } else {
                rightchild = new myTreeNode();
                rightchild.data = d;
                rightchild.parent = this;
            }
        }
    }

...more code...
}
```

it is throwing an error at "q.insert(k)" in the lab05driver.  any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

~~~~~
EDIT: sorry i jsut copied that wrong... there is a main method and Integer k is an integer...
the error im getting the command line is:
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type java.lang.Comparable

Comment: Homework? What is the compiler output?

Comment: Not an error at this line as well - `Integer k = "test"`?

Answer (score 0):

`q.insert(k);` is a statement. Statements need to be in methods, it isn't currently in a method.

So do something like:

```
public class lab05driver
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    BST q = new BST();
    int a = 5;
    String b = "jed";
    double c = 1.8;
    char d = 'r';
    boolean e = false;
    int f = 35;
    String g = "yay";
    double h = 2.1;
    char i = 'i';
    boolean j = true;

    Integer k = 1; // changed because "Integer k = "test";" doesn't compile
    q.insert(k);
  }
}
```

Note the signature I used for the method. This is the signature that Java sees as the entry method (where the program will start).

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem that I can see is:

```
    Integer k = "test";
```

k needs to be an integer of some sort - you've assigned it a String. This is not a valid assignment.  Valid values would be -1, 0, 1 etc - any integer value.

Once you assign a value value (or change k to be the `String` class) your code should be ok

Comment: Mmm - and as stated by others, your main entry point needs to be in a "main" method